# Acomodar automáticamente controles en un panel o form, vb

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Tengo que agregar por código cierta cantidad de controles a un panel, este control contiene únicamente un botón, la cuestión es como hago para que este control se acomode automáticamente al cargar, lo hice pero con `if` anidado el problema es que no se sabe cuanto pueda llegar a aumentar la cantidad de cargar ya que este depende de la cantidad de productos que maneje la empresa, he aquí el código.

```
Private Sub btnAgregar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.Click
    Dim ctrl As New CtrlMesa
    Dim x, y, ctrls As Integer
    ctrl.btnMesa.Text = "Mesa " & Mesas.Controls.Count
    If Mesas.Controls.Count <= 10 Then
        ctrls = Mesas.Controls.Count
        x = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.X
        y = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.Y
        ctrl.Location = New Point(x + 85, y)
        Mesas.Controls.Add(ctrl)
        Me.Close()
    ElseIf Mesas.Controls.Count > 10 And Mesas.Controls.Count < 22 Then

        If Mesas.Controls.Count = 11 And Mesas.Controls.Count < 22 Then
            ctrl.Location = New Point(10, 95)
            Mesas.Controls.Add(ctrl)
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf Mesas.Controls.Count > 11 Then
            ctrls = Mesas.Controls.Count
            x = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.X
            y = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.Y
            ctrl.Location = New Point(x + 85, y)
            Mesas.Controls.Add(ctrl)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    ElseIf Mesas.Controls.Count >= 22 And Mesas.Controls.Count < 33 Then
        If Mesas.Controls.Count = 22 Then
            ctrl.Location = New Point(10, y + 180)
            Mesas.Controls.Add(ctrl)
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf Mesas.Controls.Count > 22 Then
            ctrls = Mesas.Controls.Count
            x = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.X
            y = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.Y
            ctrl.Location = New Point(x + 85, y)
            Mesas.Controls.Add(ctrl)
            Me.Close()
        End If

    ElseIf Mesas.Controls.Count >= 33 And Mesas.Controls.Count <= 43 Then
        If Mesas.Controls.Count = 33 Then
            ctrl.Location = New Point(10, y + 265)
            Mesas.Controls.Add(ctrl)
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf Mesas.Controls.Count > 32 Then
            ctrls = Mesas.Controls.Count
            x = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.X
            y = Mesas.Controls.Item(ctrls - 1).Location.Y
            ctrl.Location = New Point(x + 85, y)
            Mesas.Controls.Add(ctrl)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Como pueden observar tengo un limite de 43 elementos, se que puedo agg mas pero también se que no es la manera :(

Nota: Mesas es el Form

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo hacer uso del [FlowLayoutPanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ob8P_MXB9E4) de esa forma solo necesitarías agregar los CtrlMesa al FlowLayoutPanel y este se encargaría de acomodarlos dinámica-mente:

```
Private Sub btnAgregar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAgregar.Click

    Dim ctrl As New CtrlMesa

    ctrl.btnMesa.Text = "Mesa " & Mesas.Controls.Count      

    'FlowLayoutPanel1 debe ser el control que actue como contenedor de las mesas

    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ctrl);        

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```